# Move where text starts in a text box?

Tags: html, css, textbox

I currently have a contact me box on my website with a few text boxes in it for listing your information and then a text area box for typing an email. I wanted to know if there was a way to move where the text is placed when you start typing? Currently it is right up against the left side of the box and I don't like the way it looks. I would prefer it 10px or so to the right. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: did you try padding left css option http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding-left.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a `padding-left` of `10px` to the input it will work

```css
input{
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: That seems to lengthen the box with it. I could always just make the width smaller afterwards but do you know of a way to do it without having the box lengthen?

Comment: @JustinLG99 This is how it is usually done i don't know any other methods

Answer (score 0):

You can add `padding` to the `input` box:

```css
input {
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
    margin: 20px;    
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```